# credic card page opened automatically

Tags: paypal, credit-card

I've added this button to my site.
I wish they would open the page that asks for a credit card, and not the one that asks for the login.

```
script src="paypal-button.min.js?merchant=email@gevaelettronica.it" 
    data-button="buynow" 
    data-name="Magnetoterapia MF12" 
    data-amount="238" 
    data-shipping="0"
    data-currency="EUR"    
    data-lc="it_IT" 
    data-tax="0" 
    data-callback="http://www.magnetoterapia.com/form/grazie.htm"
```

Answer (score 0):

user without a paypal account may pay you via credit card if you enable paypal optional: https://www.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=xpt/cps/general/OptionalAccount-outside

the result looks like the figure 6 you can find here: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/paypal-payments-standard/integration-guide/ProfileAndTools/

Answer (score 0):

I did not understand.
I can do what I need ?
I made a payment, recently, it is opened the default page, credit cards.